# Transform Table in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table like below:

| Name | Age | Address | Course | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 18 | Albert Garden | Business | 2020 |

Can I transpose the table into the below format?

| Name | Column | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Age | 18 |
| John | Address | Albert Garden |
| John | Course | Business |
| John | Year | 2020 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=reduce(tocol(,1),B2:index(E:E,match(,0/(A:A<>""))),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,hstack(index(A:A,row(c)),index(1:1,column(c)),c))))
```

[image]